# Как упорядочить даты на графике в порядке возрастания?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Eсть CSV файл с кол-вом заболевших за прошлый год, но он имеет неверную структуру, т.е. там сначала идет сегодняшняя дата, потом вчерашняя и т.д.

Как построить правильный график, чтобы от прошлого к настоящему, а не наоборот?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
plt.plot(data['val'])
plt.show()
```

Пробовал: `data = data[::-1]`

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у столбец с датами имеет тип данных `datetime64`, то `Pandas` сам позаботится о сортировке значений по оси `X`.

Пример:

```
In [105]: df = pd.DataFrame({"DT": pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=20), "val": np.random.randint(100, size=20)}).sample(frac=1)

In [106]: df
Out[106]:
           DT  val
15 2021-01-16   71
2  2021-01-03   23
11 2021-01-12   29
3  2021-01-04   66
0  2021-01-01   52
9  2021-01-10   78
18 2021-01-19    5
12 2021-01-13   64
8  2021-01-09   81
6  2021-01-07   73
13 2021-01-14   85
10 2021-01-11   85
7  2021-01-08   74
1  2021-01-02   49
4  2021-01-05   80
14 2021-01-15   38
19 2021-01-20   98
5  2021-01-06   25
17 2021-01-18    3
16 2021-01-17   69
```

рисуем средствами Pandas:

```
In [108]: df.set_index("DT")["val"].plot()
Out[108]: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='DT'>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, кстати, да. Сущности, которые понятно как сортировать, `Pandas` сам должен правильно по оси `x` располагать и правда.

Comment: @CrazyElf, он как бы не должен, но любезно делает это :-D

Answer (score 4):

Отсортируйте датафрейм по тому столбцу, где у вас даты. Примерно так:

```
data = data.sort_values('dt') # ну или как у вас столбец с датой называется
```

Либо, если даты в индексе:

```
data = data.sort_index()
```

Но всё-равно могут быть проблемы, если даты у вас не типа "дата", а виде строк в не очень сортируемом формате каком-то (например MM/DD/YYYY), тогда их лучше перевести сначала в настоящие даты (или хотя бы в хорошо сортируемые строки формата YYYY/MM/DD), а потом уже сортировать.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то непонятное вы говорите.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dt=np.arange('2021-02-01', '2021-02-11', dtype='datetime64[D]')
dt1=np.arange(10)
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':dt,'B':dt1})
df1=df[::-1]
```

ДатаФрейм  df -  порядок "прямой".

```
Out[20]: 
           A  B
0 2021-02-01  0
1 2021-02-02  1
2 2021-02-03  2
3 2021-02-04  3
4 2021-02-05  4
5 2021-02-06  5
6 2021-02-07  6
7 2021-02-08  7
8 2021-02-09  8
9 2021-02-10  9
```

ДатаФрейм df1 -  порядок "обратный":

```
Out[21]: 
           A  B
9 2021-02-10  9
8 2021-02-09  8
7 2021-02-08  7
6 2021-02-07  6
5 2021-02-06  5
4 2021-02-05  4
3 2021-02-04  3
2 2021-02-03  2
1 2021-02-02  1
0 2021-02-01  0
```

Как видите, все прекрасно "переворачивается" конструкцией df1=df[::-1].

Но если речь идет только о выводе графика без создания промежуточного ДатаФрейма, тогда вот так:

```
ax.plot(df.A,df.B)
ax.invert_xaxis()
```

Результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видите, все также отлично "переворачивается"

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь. Как я говорил, при `data1 = data[::-1]` при построении графика ничего не меняется, если бы дата была в нормальном формате, можно было бы использовать предложенные вами способы. Я же решил просто перевести в список.

```
data_val = list(data['val'][::-1])
```